# ## in python using notepad++ syntax coloring

Tags: python, comments

In my editor (notepad++) in Python script edit mode, a line

```
## is this a special comment or what?
```

Turns a different color (yellow) than a normal #comment.

What's special about a ##comment vs a #comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Python point of view, there's no difference. However, Notepad++'s highlighter considers the ## sequence as a STRINGEOL, which is why it colours it this way. See this [thread](http://sourceforge.net/forum/message.php?msg_id=4340178).

Answer (score 3):

I thought the difference had something to do with usage:

```
#this is a code block header
```

vs.

```
##this is a comment
```

I know Python doesn't care one way or the other, but I thought it was just convention to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in a [different situations](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/doc-sig/2006-March/003558.html):

> Comment whose first line is a double hash:
>
> > This is used by doxygen and Fredrik Lundh's PythonDoc.  In doxygen,
> >     if there's text on the line with the double hash, it is treated as
> >     a summary string.  I dislike this convention because it seems too
> >     likely to result in false positives.  E.g., if you comment-out a
> >     region with a comment in it, you get a double-hash.